# makefile to take dependency of all file in particular directory

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies, header-files

I have a c++ project. In my Project folder, I have three sub project folders.

```
Proj_Folder
   Include
       head1.h
       head2.h
       ....
   Sub_Proj1
       proj1.cpp
       makefile
   Sub_Proj2
      proj2.cpp
      makefile
   Sub_Proj3
      proj3.cpp
      makefile
ShareAll.cpp
makefile
```

This is makefile in the folder of 'Proj_Folder'.

```
OBJS =  ../ShareAll.o proj1.o

proj1: ${OBJS}
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $+

proj1.o : proj1.cpp
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

../ShareAll.o : ../ShareAll.cpp
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

I need include all the header files which is located in the directory 'Include' as dependency for whole project.

I tried this below code.

```
C_HEADER_FILES := $(patsubst Include/*.h)

# The dependency file names.
DEPS := $(C_HEADER_FILES:.h=.d)

# Let make read the dependency files and handle them.
-include $(DEPS)
```

But It says,

```
makefile:30: *** insufficient number of arguments (1) to function `patsubst'.  Stop.
```

How can I include all the header files as dependency in this project makefile?

Comment: The "correct" way of handling this would be to have GCC generate dependency files with something like `-MMD`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function to collect the set of .h files. You need to use:

```
C_HEADER_FILES := $(wildcard Include/*.h)
```